# Is it make sense to throw exception in string type's extension method when type converting faild?

Tags: c#, extension-methods

We're writing extension method for string type to process type converting. We have two solutions, and not sure which one is better.

solution 1:

```
public static int? ToIntNull(this string str)
    {
        int value;
        bool parseSucceed = int.TryParse(str, out value);
        if (parseSucceed)
        {
            return value;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Solution 2:

```
 public static int toInt(this string input, bool throwExceptionIfFailed = false)
{
    int result;
    var valid = int.TryParse(input, out result);
    if (!valid)
        if (throwExceptionIfFailed)
            throw new FormatException(string.Format("'{0}' cannot be converted as int", input));
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> `int.TryParse()` is generally used to avoid throwing exception in the case of
>   conversion failure. it will give result as `0` to the out parameter
>   and return false in case of failure conversions.

If you want to deal with the thrown exception, you can try `int.Parse` instead for `int.TryParse()`; If you want to deal with exception you can simply use `parse()` enclosed within a `try..catch`, like the following;

```
 try
  {
    int result = Int32.Parse("str"); 
    //if it failes, will throw an exception
  }
 catch (Exception ex)
  {
   //handle the exception here
  }
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Yes, this is my question, is it make sense to throw exception here? Or just return default value if conversion failed.